# Convolution of compactly supported distributions

Tags: distribution-theory

Is the convolution of two compactly supported distributions of non disjoint supports always defined? If yes is it itself compactly supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. If $T,S$ are compactly supported with compact supports $K_T$, $K_S$ respectively, then $T\ast S$ is also compactly supported, and supp$(T\ast S)\subset K_T+K_S:=\{t+s: t\in K_T,\; s\in K_S\}$. Refernce: Schwartz's books on distribution theory.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. By the way, I ordered Schwartz' book "Théorie des distributions".

Comment: I just checked and it appears as Theorem II on page 126, Section 3 of Chapter VI. :-)